# How to configure lightpd to block http connection only for external IP's and not for localhost

Tags: lighttpd

How to configure lightpd to block http connection only for external IP's and not for localhost

I have made lighttpd to listen on port 443, but this makes localhost too not able to make http request. I want an exception for localhost. Can someone please suggest any option?

Comment: Sorry for confusing text, I will refrase it again. I meant I want the lighttpd to bind to 443 and so all IP's will need to use https request. This I have already done. But for localhost I want to allow http connection.

Answer (score 0):

```
server.bind = "127.0.0.1"
server.port = 80
$SERVER["socket"] == ":443" {
    # ...
}
```

https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_Configuration